# Turn source code to application in c++

Tags: c++

I was wondering how to convert my source code to a working application.
What I mean is after I write my code I want to make app out of it. So I can use it with out a compiler running it.

Comment: You run the compiler on it, and afterwards you have an executable binary.

Comment: You're using an IDE. The IDE builds an executable application and then runs it. Where to find that executable so you can run it yourself depends on your IDE.

Comment: It depends upon the operating system and compiler.  If you are using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. on Linux) save your source file into `mysource.cc` then compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g mysource.cc -o myprog` then run `./myprog` (perhaps inside the `gdb` debugger)

Comment: This is arguably a very `rudimentary question` best served by a _Learning c++ 101_ book or tutorial rather than being on SO.  Also it's arguably **too broad** as it stands without knowing more.  You didn't tell us if your source code is a static library; or dynamic library that needs to be linked to another `application` that you are yet to write.  Not to mention what `operating system`; `compiler`; or if there are `unicorns`.  Please help us help you by posting additional info

Answer (score 0):

After you compile, an executable file is created in the location the source code is saved to. For example, if you save your source code to a folder named C++, then in that very folder, an executable file is created which has the same name as the source code. Here's an example, I saved my source code as "aa" into the folder "C++". Now as you can see in the image, there are two "aa"'s, one is the source code, while the other is the executable program ( Well, this is the case in most C++ compilers anyway ).
[image]

Well, hope this helps you   :)

Comment: Most (actually all that I know) compilers are a command line program. Your IDE might run a compiler for you, but you should also be able to run the compiler in the terminal. Details are operating system and compiler specific.